# LazyLoadingException in transactional method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, jakarta-ee

I am using a service layer component in my web layer that returns an entity. This entity has lazy loaded collections. This is part of a mapping process between resource objects and domain objects. I get ids from the REST clients and I look up domain objects based on the id.

After mapping these objects are passed to the service layer:

```
@Transactional
public Result assess(Pet pet) { ... }
```

Mapping example:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", nullable = false)
public Set<Owner> getOwners() {
    return owners;
}
```

Why do I get LazyLoadingException inside this method? The pet object was retrieved in the web layer, but I am only accessing the properties inside a transactional method.

I am using Spring 3.2.x and Hibernate 4.2.x

Steps that happens in my application (RESTful backend system).

1. User submits a resource with only ids for different entities. I am associating existing entiteis with each other.
2. The Spring MVC part maps the resource objects to domain objects and look up the entities based on the id. This is done with a component annotated as @Service with @Transactional on the method.
3. The domain object is passed to another service where I am accessing the relations, however this fails since it is lazy loaded. However, the method also has @Transactional.

Comment: Without seeing related hbm (or) annotations, hard to answer.

Comment: @Nambari Updated with mapping example.

Comment: Well you are using FetchType.Lazy, so it will not load until needed. That part I am not clear is, you are saying call is inside Transaction, but I suspect it is not. I think the "Transaction" you are referring here is different from database transaction. I would suggest add Debug pointers and try.

Comment: @Nambari Added more text

Comment: "The domain object is passed to another service where I am accessing the relations", I guess when hibernate does lazy lookup, it should be inside same transaction boundaries, but in your case it is happening in new transaction boundary in new service. Let us see if experts have any comments on this. But I would suggest change to EAGER for quick hack to make it work as you expected (OR) do new lookup in second service.

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is what happens too. I would quess doing another look up in the service is cleaner.

Comment: I think this happens because you don't handle a session yourself, i mean accros your services. And because there is no session, contexts are closed on commit, i.e when you go out your transaction(s). This is why you have such exception with lazy load. Either use your services in the same transaction flow, or manage session accros your services.

Comment: @kij: I hope "session" you mean hibernate session.

Comment: Yep sorry. @Lucky: may this page help you: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions  Edit: just found this related question whith a good (and clearer) answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837169/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-how-to-properly-use-hibernates-lazy

Comment: As far as you didn't specified any config for delegating transactions, i'm almost sure that you can initialize lazy loaded properties before moving to next service method using `Hibernate.initialize(provide object you want to init)`. This way you get the properties in the next method already initialized. This is sort of a workaround, we could provide a better approach if you provide more details in config.