# Hibernate/Jpa OneToMany not retrieving data properly

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-onetomany

I have an entity class named User which contains this OneToMany column for database:

```
  @Setter
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user")
    @JoinTable(
        name = "USER_CARS",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="CAR_ID", referencedColumnName = "id")
    )
    private List<Car> cars;
```

When I'm inserting an user into database, everything works fine, and his cars are also added in user_cars table. When retrieving the cars i get this exception:

```
Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.
```

I've searched for other answers but didn't found how to solve it. This is how I'm trying to retrieve the User.

```
public T findById(Long id) {
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
    em.getTransaction().begin();

    T et = (T) em.find(entityClass, id);

    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();

    return et;
}
```

What is the problem and how can I fix it? I can't understand what's going on in background.

Comment: You can test with `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` in `@OneToMany` annotation first. Default fetch type is `Lazy` for many side. I think you have to initialise all cars related to user in transaction bountry with `Hibernate.initialize()` method. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5837169/org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-how-to-properly-use-hibernates-lazy) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542140/hibernate-org-hibernate-lazyinitializationexception-could-not-initialize-proxy) for more details.

Comment: When exactly do you got this exception? You will see it when you try to access lazy-loaded properties when `session` is no longer available. You may want to make it available as an alternative to eager loading.

Comment: This exception is seen (while debuging) when trying to see user cars in the retrieved data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the exception message, it seems that you are retrieving the content of the `List` cars but the `EntityManager` session is already closed. Rather than the default lazy initialization for the collection you could use

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
```